# When is the most efficient time to populate a large select dropdown in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu, backbone.js

I've been struggling with this for a bit. I'm using backbone to render models, and chosen plugin for my dropdowns.

When a new collection comes in, the jQuery slideDown effect is used to render each model. Each model has a select dropdown that needs to be populated with over 600 options.

The problem I'm running into is that if I populate the dropdowns first, then the slideDown animation is choppy, and in fact is usually just ignored (suddenly my models appear, no animation.)

Another option I've tried is rendering the models first, appending only the model's value for the specific dropdown, and then setting it's selected value. Then, a setTimeout is called and the rest of the options are populated (behind the scenes). However in that case there ends up being an obvious, annoying delay. If I don't set the Timeout, then it tries to fill dropdowns that don't yet exist.

Am I missing something in how to do this efficiently? I'm caching my list of options for the select dropdown. I've tried both looping through all the options into a string and replacing the html of the dropdown, and looping through each option and appending one at a time.

I think my problem has more to do with the combination of animation and 600+ options for the dropdowns. Ideally, after the model appears, it would immediately populate the dropdown list with no delay.

Comment: I would use a typeahead instead (see [this demo](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) for what I mean). 600 options in a dropdown are not user friendly.

Comment: 600 options are never efficient to select

Comment: Unfortunately this is not something I have control over. I need to use select dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a timeout. You could create your own [event](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) in backbone.

```
initialize: function () {
  // When our event is triggered, load the dropdowns.
  this.on( 'doneWithThings', this.loadDropdowns );
},

// render the view
render: function () {
  // Whatever it is that you do when rendering.
  // When you're done rendering, trigger an event.
  this.trigger( 'doneWithThings' );
},

loadDropdowns: function () {
  // Load them!
}
```

Other things I would try...

Keep the options in the client-side (JS array), but don't draw them to the screen unless the user has expanded that slideDown section of the screen. Again, raise an event when the slideDown effect happens.

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally, after the model appears, it would immediately populate the
>   dropdown list with no delay.

Dont know blackbone but if there is some animation,you could look at  [jquery .promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)

```
$(":animated").promise().done(function() {
    //load data
  });​
```